# Installing tool from github scimpute

Tags: r, devtools, r-usethis

I am trying to install a tool from github following there instruction, (https://github.com/Vivianstats/scImpute) but facing problem with installation

Below code Is the code I have run for installation:

```
install.packages("devtools")

library(devtools)
install_github("Vivianstats/scImpute")
```

When i am loading library i am getting error:
loading required package: usethis"

session info usethis is already there, can anyone help me to install this tool

```
 sessionInfo()
```

Comment: "loading required package: usethis" isn't an error message, it's an informatyional message.  Do you get any other messages?

Comment: @Limey Thanks for your replay , ran 'install_github("Vivianstats/scImpute")' command without erorr , when i am calling scimpute getting erorr as '''Error: object 'scImpute' not found ''"

Comment: Then you need to show us the code that failed (along with the associated error messages), not the code that worked!  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) may help you create a simple, self-contained example.